# Most efficient way to make range between 2 numbers

Tags: python-3.x

Right now i'm using the simple for loop,

```
p1 += ([(x,i) for i in range(j,y+1)])
```

Just an example from my code, i'm making ranges of tuples, for example

j = 1, y= 9998 , x=1

So I should get `(1,1),(1,2)......(1,9998)` It's a list of tuples.

The loop will take a lot of time if we having big number.

There is a way to improve without using libraries.

Comment: How is `x` defined?

Comment: you could try `p1 += ((x,i) for i in range(j,y+1))`  (no list comprehension just generator comprehension, not sure it helps, though.

Comment: is `p1` a `tuple` of `tuples` or a list? can you create a [mcve] ?

Comment: @blhsing I edited, for example x =1

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't think that will help, thank you anyway :)
p1 should be alist of tuples in ranges that described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `zip(iter1, iter2, ...)` function to create an iterator wich yields a tuple consisting of the elements in the iterables passed in the argument.
Use `itertools.cycle()` to provide the constant element in your tuples.

You can save time if you use the iterator returned by the `zip()` (i.e not making it a `list()`), but you can only use that once. If the iterator is exhausted you need to create a new one, but that is ridiculously fast.

That way is about 30% faster, on Python 3.7.1
 Here is the code to test it yourself:

```
import timeit
from itertools import cycle

x = 5
j = 1
y = 10000

def method1():
    return [(x, i) for i in range(j, y + 1)]

cycling_x = cycle([x])
def method2():
    return list(zip(cycling_x, range(j, y + 1)))

print(timeit.timeit("method1()", number=10000, globals=globals()))
print(timeit.timeit("method2()", number=10000, globals=globals()))
```

`>>> 10.956179626`

`>>> 7.571100585999998`

Answer (score 2):

The [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function combines two iterators into a series of tuples.  [`itertools.repeat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) creates an iterator that always yields the same object.

```
import itertools
zip(itertools.repeat(x), range(j, y+1))
```

This will return a lazy iterator, which you can loop over once (e.g. `for a, b in zip(...): ...`).  If you want all of the tuples collected into a list which you can access repeatedly and out of order, call `list()` on the result of `zip(...)`.